# A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

Tags: .net, wpf, openfiledialog, win32exception

I have a .NET 4.0 WPF project.

When I open a FileDialog, choose some files and press the OK button, then I see in the output window this error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in WindowsBase.dll

```
OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Multiselect = true;

            DialogResult result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
```

Why do I get that Exception before the if-statement?

Comment: my crystal ball is in the shop. Care adding some details like the stacktrace?

Comment: there is no stacktrace because the exception was thrown silently... application continued to run...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're seeing a `Win32Exception` which was raised and handled within the WPF application stack.  I've seen this happen many times when debugging WPF applications.  They make API calls which can fail, handle the exception and continue processing.

It's nothing to be concerned about unless the exception makes it way back to your code.

Comment: Well when its handled from wpf why should I handle it? Nothing happens, its just during debugging so... I will follow your last advise and be happy :)