# C# and WPF, ShowFIleDialog throw an excpetion

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I have a problem with my code. I use OpenFileDialog in my project and when I call the method ShowDialog an exception is thrown. I don't understand why.

```
    private void open_FileMenu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog browser = new OpenFileDialog();
        browser.AddExtension = true;
        browser.Filter = "Audio, Video File | *.wma; *.mp3; *.wmv";
        browser.Title = "Choose your file";
         if (browser.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes) // Exception thrown here
          {
            try
            {
                string FileName = browser.FileName;
                MyMedia.Source = new Uri(FileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

This exception said

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred  in WindowsBase.dl
```

Additional information: Incorrect parameter

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283804/a-first-chance-exception-of-type-system-componentmodel-win32exception-occurred

Comment: So I skip this exception. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

In WinForms `CommonDialog.ShowDialog()` comes from [System.Windows.Forms.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e61ft40c.aspx) and returns a `DialogResult`.

In WPF `CommonDialog.ShowDialog()` comes from [PresentationFramework.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms614336.aspx) and returns a `bool?`

Naturally this leads to a lot of confusion. Ultimately you want this instead.

```
if (browser.ShowDialog() == true)
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
        OpenFileDialog browser = new OpenFileDialog();
        browser.AddExtension = true;
        browser.Filter = "Audio, Video File | *.wma; *.mp3; *.wmv";
        browser.Title = "Choose your file";
        string FileName;
        bool? res = browser.ShowDialog(); // No exception thrown here
        if (res ?? false)
        {
            try
            {
                 FileName = browser.FileName;
                //MyMedia.Source = new Uri(FileName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```